What to do when you get "DiscardVirtualMemory could not be located" error once GitHub Desktop is installed
This will happen to those who are still using Windows 7 for whatever good reason.
Full error message will be,

The procedure entry point DiscardVirtualMemory could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll


Note that this particular need for a solution has emerged during the development of https://speakworldlanguages.github.io/

What you need to do is, uninstall the version of Github Desktop that is TOO NEW for Windows 7. Then install v3.2.4
To find the installer go to,
https://desktop.githubusercontent.com/?page=3
or
https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/17209#issuecomment-1677203754
Once you see this you are good to go.

